# Create multiple dropdown lists dynamically from database in sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

Firstly, I apologise if this has already been asked and answered, been searching for hours trying to find help and keep drawing blanks.

Basically what I need is this. I have to create a help page. This help page is similar in format to what you would expect at a hardware driver site. The first dropdown box might contain the manufactures name. Once the name is selected the second dropdown box lists all relevant categories (perhaps the model numbers), and the third dropdown box might list the actual hardware for that model (hdd's, video hardware, audio hardware and such like).

I need three dropdown boxes that work in this fashion. All the data is in a single database with multiple tables, I'm working with Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008, ASP.NET, C#. Can anyone point me in the right direction for a walkthrough or tutorial or whatever that might help?

Thanks in advance.
David

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question- if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tutorial on using the cascade drop down list from the AJAX control toolkit:

[Using CascadingDropDown with a Database](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Walkthrough/CCDWithDB.aspx)

This control from Microsoft fills your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the selectedindexchanged event of the drop down with autopostback=true